# Angular using rxjs operator to change boolean flag

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to refactor a get http request. The code that I'm using now is getting the data from service and in the subscribe method also changing a boolean flag

```
 this.eventsService.getEvents(this.pageSize, this.currentPage).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    this.busy = false
    this.events = data.events
  }
);
```

I've refactor to use Observable on my view, and this code looks this way now, component code:

```
const $results = this.eventsService.getEvents(this.pageSize, this.currentPage);
this.$events = $results.pipe(tap(() => { this.busy = false } ), map(data => data.events));
```

view code (nativescript) :

```
<ListView *ngIf="!busy" [items]="$events | async" ></ListView>
```

it does provide proper content in the view but the **busy** flag is not changed in the tap operator. Is it feasible to somehow change boolean in the pipe() ?

Comment: Where is the subscribe in the refactored code?  I'm not sure about the context of this code. Is it in a method? Should it be `this.$results`?

Comment: I'm using async pipe in the view file

Comment: With which stream? `$results` or `$events`?

Comment: $events, I've added one line from my view in the description

Comment: If it's displaying the proper content in the view, then `busy` must be false? (Your refactored code looks basically OK, so wondering if there is something else amiss?)

Comment: what is not working is the flag busy not changed to false. I set it to true before I call the service (busy true renders  spinner in the ui) and after the call to service is completed I would like to switch off the spinner and show the data.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the UI binding as discussed by @Gael below. (I just build a stackblitz that demonstrates it.)

Comment: thanks that is correct

Comment: Here's a link to the stackblitz if it's at all useful: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-update-flag-in-pipe-deborahk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is:

- your component won't be displayed until `busy` is false because of `*ngIf="!busy"`
- the `$events` won't be subscribed until the component is displayed (reminder: nothing happens in an `Observable` chain until there's a subscription)

Thus this cannot work: the subscription will not happen because the flag is true, and the flag will stay true because there's no subscription.

To workaround this, I'd subscribe in the Typescript code and get rid of the `async` pipe.